# Rotating device changing image orientation ?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation

This is my camera Activity which is in Portrait mode. I am rotating the device and the camera is rotating with it.

[image: Camera]

This is my second `Activity` where my image is displaying on the `ImageView` upside down, received from `PictureCallback()`. I already tried `ExifInterface` but its returning orientation 0.

[image: second]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Problem. Orientation 0 in ExifInterface means undefined. If that occurs i ask the MediaStore and in my case it always returns the correct orientation if ExifInterface returns 0.

```
String[] cols = { MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION };
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, cols, null, null, null);
int orientation = 0;

if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
        orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION));
}
```

Comment: Still getting orientation = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Setting for camera:

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
            int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
        try {

            android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
            android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getRotation();
            int degrees = 0;
            switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
            }

            int result;
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
            } else { // back-facing
                result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
            }
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
```

And use ExifInterface  when display result